# About thread-safety using QThreadStorage

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

This is a threading question where I basically started making a library thread-safe. My use-case is as follows -

```
struct <>
    {

      int thread_specific_value;
}
```

1) Spin 5 threads for example.

2) Each thread does operation and store thread_specific_value in the above data structure for example. This is dynamically allocated at the initialization of each thread and added to QThreadStorage.

3) Once all threads return to main thread, I like to access the errno values of all threads and do some processing. Before I delete the thread from the main thread, can I get the information of its storage data and store in main thread's specific storage.

In nutshell, how can I iterate through QThreadStorage of all the thread specific stored data and do some processing from main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data stored in QThreadStorage is accessible only from the thread that put it there. Period. If you want to access the same data from other threads, you must store it additionally elsewhere. In particular, the thread-specific value is destroyed on thread exit; if you want to keep the value, save it somewhere before the thread exits.

In short, don't try to use QThreadStorage for inter-thread communication. That's not what it's there for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said earlier, I am not deleting the thread. So as per the documentation, thread specific data is not destroyed. Is there any other custom open source thread storage data structure I can use which can employ this accessibility?

Comment: "QThreadStorage takes ownership of the data (which must be created on the heap with new) and deletes it when the thread exits, either normally or via termination." - when it terminates, not when it's deleted. It's not hard to roll your own method of communicating data out of the thread though, and there's enough difference in use cases that I'm not aware of any really standardized methods... (plus exposing TLS is a very rare use case...)

Comment: We can still use QThreadStorage for certain kind of interthread communication. Say, to tag the thread with some marker which is recognized by common function. I use it for recognizing the "name" of the thread the code is running on.

Comment: @AlexanderV A `QThread` has a name, since it is a `QObject`. You can just set its name and call it a day... You can also use the fast, but undocumented `setUserData` with custom data.

Comment: @KubaOber I see and at the time I just had that local thread storage with the name and used it while I could have named QObject as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply on a question solved for over 9 years. I'm looking for a solution for a similar question like this one and I'm inspired by this sentence from the accepted answer by @bdonlan:

```
If you want to access the same data from other threads, you must store it additionally elsewhere.
```

So, instead of storing a copy elsewhere, you could just store the only copy elsewhere, i.e. in the main thread, collect all copies for different threads in a container (list or a map, but not a std::vector or QVector). Then, in each thread, the QThreadStorage stores a pointer to the copy in the main thread. Note, as long as the copy only get accessed by one thread, it's the same.

When a thread allocates a the data in the main thread's container, you'll still need a lock. But ongoing access won't need any lock.

In the end, all threads returns to the main thread, you can access the container lock free.